# JAVA GUI drawing objects with buttons in multiple windows

Tags: java, user-interface, button, radio-button, drawing

So, i have a question with me code here, i have to make a program that draws objects and sometime fills them by clicking radiobuttons, the other part is that the drawing part had to be done in a second window, so i need to have the radiobuttons in one screen and by clicking them i have to draw objects in different window. I maded up to the part where i declared the buttons and created the 2nd screen, but i dont know how to make when i select the radiobutton to draws in the 2nd screen, can someone help me, im new into JAVA.
`

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ButtonWindow extends JFrame{

        JRadioButton Oval, Line,OutlineColor1,OutlineColor2,OutlineColor3,FillColor1,FillColor2,FillColor3;
        
        ButtonWindow(){
            JFrame f1=new JFrame();
            this.setTitle("Drawing Objects");
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            this.pack();
            this.setSize(500,500);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            
            setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        
              Oval = new JRadioButton("Oval shape ");   
              Line = new JRadioButton("Line");
              OutlineColor1 = new JRadioButton("Outline Color: RED");
              OutlineColor2 = new JRadioButton("Outline Color: BLUE");
              OutlineColor3 = new JRadioButton("Outline Color: GREEN");
              FillColor1 = new JRadioButton("Filling Color: RED");
              FillColor2 = new JRadioButton("Filling Color: BLUE");
              FillColor3 = new JRadioButton("Filling Color: GREEN");
             
             ButtonGroup group1 = new ButtonGroup();
                group1.add(Oval);
                group1.add(Line);
                
                ButtonGroup group2 = new ButtonGroup();
                group2.add(OutlineColor1);
                group2.add(OutlineColor2);
                group2.add(OutlineColor3);
                
                ButtonGroup group3 = new ButtonGroup();
                group3.add(FillColor1);
                group3.add(FillColor2);
                group3.add(FillColor3);                         
                
             this.add(Oval);        
             this.add(Line);            
             this.add(OutlineColor1);           
             this.add(OutlineColor2);           
             this.add(OutlineColor3);            
             this.add(FillColor1);          
             this.add(FillColor2);          
             this.add(FillColor3);      
        }
}
```

`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ObjectWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    
    ButtonWindow ButtonWindow;
    
    ObjectWindow(ButtonWindow bw){
        this.ButtonWindow =bw;
        this.setTitle("Drawing Objects");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
    
     this.setSize(1000, 1000);
     this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        
    }


}
```

`

```
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;

public class main {
    public static void main(String a[]){
        ButtonWindow window = new ButtonWindow();
        new ObjectWindow(window);
        
       
    }

}
```

Comment: You should almost never create classes that extend from JFrame. Much better/flexible to extend from JPanel and then put it in a JFrame

Comment: What you'll want is something like the Area classes here: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/ (AreaManager is the right place to get started in looking at how all this works together)

Comment: @ControlAltDel i see, i looked about that link u sended, but i couldnt understand much whats going on there, as i said im new at JAVA i cant understand these complicated manager stuffs, it might be the base level for you but i cant sorry, i just want to know what kind of functions or whatever i have to use to make my radiobuttons to draw objects in another screen, every one of these examples are drawing objects in the same screen u making the buttons, thats the easy part but i cant with 2 screens for some reason.

Comment: I recommend you do the Swing trails on Oracle's website